# Extra bytes added using rijndael decrypt

Tags: c#, php

I've ported over some C# to PHP as to which I thought was successful, it turns out that the PHP version of `phpseclib` is appending extra random bytes to my result.

Here's my C# result in what it should be:

[image: C# result]

And here's my PHP result, as you can see it appends random bytes to the string.

[image]

The PHP functionality I'm using to decode is:

```
$rijndael = new Rijndael();
$rijndael->setKey(hex2bin($rgbKey));
$rijndael->setIV(hex2bin($rgbIv));
$rijndael->setKeyLength(256);
$rijndael->setBlockLength(128);
$rijndael->disablePadding();

$result = $rijndael->decrypt(rtrim(hex2bin(implode("", $hexdata))));
```

The C# function that's decoding is:

```
int num2 = 0;
int count1 = rijndaelManaged.BlockSize / 8;
byte[] buffer4 = new byte[count1];
fileStream.Seek((long)Start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
    while (fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length - 128L) {
        int count2 = fileStream.Read(buffer4, 0, count1);
        num2 += count2;
        cryptoStream.Write(buffer4, 0, count2);
        if (count2 <= 0)
            break;
    }
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    cryptoStream.Close();
}
fileStream.Close();
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction to prevent the extra bytes that'd be great, the other thing I should note is the amount of extra bytes vary based on the file which is decoded

Comment: The purpose (or validity) of `fileStream.Length - 128L` isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that removing `$rijndael->disablePadding();` fixed the problem!

Comment: There are like 6 things to set when you want to encrypt something, to be sure that you can decrypt it in another language (that uses different defaults in its implementation): algorithm (AES, ...), key length (128, 256...), block length (with aes it is fixed), mode (CBC, ECB...), padding (PKCS7...), Encoding if you are working with strings (UTF8, ...). Plus clearly Key and IV. You are leaving to fate Padding and Mode.